# Umbraco MemberService very slow

Tags: c#, umbraco

I'm tying to list all the members by type and do a pagination, but as soon as I call method **GetMembersByMemberType** it just wont move. It takes around 8 to 9 minutes to list and I only have little over 4000 members.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please.

```
var ms = ApplicationContext.Services.MemberService;
IEnumerable<IMember> list = null;
list = ms.GetMembersByMemberType("Candidato").Where(x => x.IsApproved == true).OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(10);
```

Thanks,

Comment: is there a way to do that work on your service side?

Comment: You mean inside the MemberService? It's native on the Umbraco CMS, I can't access it.

Comment: What version of Umbraco are you using - 6 or 7, the exact version number would be useful in case there were changes to the service?

Comment: I only have a v6 site to hand with 000's of members and I see the same behaviour. Running a SQL profiler I can see LOT's of SELECTS taking place to get property data, do you have many properties on the MemberType?

Comment: Are you by any chance seeing this when the debugger is attached in your local environment? Detaching the debugger I saw this load ~4700 in 6-7 secs locally.

Comment: Yes I've got around 30 properties per member. I'm analysing the database and it looks like the tables don't have indexes, I'm going to add them to see if if helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87878/discussion-between-pronotion-and-kup).

Answer (score 0):

The member service is quite heavy on the DB calls. The members get saved into an Examine index, you could try querying that instead, as that should be MUCH faster.